# Powernap fails to start

Tags: server, 18.04, services, wakeonlan, powernap

I want to shut down or suspend my little home server after a while and wake it when a magic packet comes so I've installed powernap to suspend my server. But when trying to start powernap service with `sudo service powernap start` it gives me an error: `Failed to start powernap.service: Unit network.service not found.` I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

with ethtool I don't know how to set permanently the `wake-on` on g

any help? :D

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. 
This is a known bug with a workaround here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/powernap/+bug/1608057

Edit: `/lib/systemd/system/powernap.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=PowerNap
Requires=networking.service
After=networking.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/usr/share/powernap/powernap-ethtool
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/powernapd
ExecStop=-/usr/sbin/powerwake-now
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then restart `powernap`:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start powernap
```